# Client Error 404 not found when sending a post request with guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5.4, guzzle

I want to send a post request to an external api using guzzle , but i get this error : 

Client error: `POST https://api.platform.ly/` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response:

```
{"status":"error","message":"Missing Parameters"}
```

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
         $url = "https://api.platform.ly/";
         $body['api_key'] = ENV('PLATFORMLY_KEY');
         $body['action'] = 'add_contact';
         $body['value'] = [
             'project_id' => '1589',
             'email' => $user->email,
             'name' => $user->name
         ];
         $request = $client->post($url, ['form_params'=>$body]);
         dd($request);
         $response = $request->send();
         dd($response);
```

Comment: Have you verified all your variables are really set correctly?  Does `ENV()` in caps really work?  [Lower-case `env()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#retrieving-environment-configuration) is the normal, documented way. Are you using config caching?  If so you should not be calling `env()`, [as the docs warn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/configuration#configuration-caching).

Comment: There is no problem with `env` the body variable is just fine before sending , it contains all what i need .

Comment: I think `$client->post()` already returns a `ResponseInterface`, so there's no need to `send()` it afaik. Also according to [api.platform.ly documentation](https://api-docs.io/preview/JassnE9G2TWjwXZP6/contacts/add_contact?apiKey=XjGxvJgPbZybwm26u) the `project_id` should be an integer, not a string.

Comment: The error is happening before calling the `send()` method so the problem isn't there (You can see a `dd($request)` before `send()` ) And for the `project_id` , i changed it into an integer but i have the same problem

Comment: If you check the documentation, you need to send params as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem.  A JSON string is needed on the `value` field per platformly docs, so utilize `json_encode` like so.

```
$body['value'] = json_encode([
  'project_id' => '1589',
  'email' => $user->email,
  'name' => $user->name
]);
```

I had the same issue and it took a min to figure it out because it wasn't clear.

Here is your code snippet with json_encode implemented.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
         $url = "https://api.platform.ly/";
         $body['api_key'] = ENV('PLATFORMLY_KEY');
         $body['action'] = 'add_contact';
         $body['value'] = json_encode([
             'project_id' => '1589',
             'email' => $user->email,
             'name' => $user->name
         ]);
         $request = $client->post($url, ['form_params'=>$body]);
         dd($request);
         $response = $request->send();
         dd($response);
```